# "Open as Lens" brings up only 100 entries. How to bring all the entries?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I have different lens in a dashboard. And "Open as Lens" option is available in each of the lenses.

When I click on Open as Lens option and click on Raw Data, only top 100 entries are displayed. I also checked with SAQL query and the limit has been set to 100 for it. I cannot change it.

Is there any other way through which I can display all the entries in the Lens?

Comment: I want the default limit to be 1000

Answer (score 1):

There's a new [Expert Editor mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_modify.htm) in Spring 16 release which should let you see all the JSON data. Also, you can use the limit parameter as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_query.htm) to increase the number of records.

Answer (score 1):

when you go to saql editor, you would see `q = limit q by 100;` please remove this.
If you cannot find it, in query node add limit to high value

```
"query": {
    "measure": ["count", *],
    "groups": [],
    "limit": 10000000000
}
```

It could degrade the dashboard performance.